# Exclude table using CrudRepository in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i have two tables Person and PersonType and there is a relation "ManyToMany" between these tables. During loading my application i am getting all the PersonTypes, but when i create new Person, i have an exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "person_type_person_type_name_key" 
Detail: Key (person_type_name)=(TYPE1) already exists.
```

person_type_person_type_name_key is my table where i should store the relations between Person and PersonType. When i create a new Person i DO NOT want to insert into PersonType table because the person type already exists. What should i do, not to insert into DB ? I am using personService.save(person); which is trying to insert also in person_type table into DB.

````
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "person_id_seq")
 @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "person_id_seq", name = "person_id_seq", schema = "manager", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
 private Integer id;

 @Column(name = "name")
 private String name;

 @Column(name = "password")
 private String password;

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
 @JoinTable(
         name = "person_person_types",
         joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_fk"),
         inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_type_fk"))
 private List<PersonType> personTypes;
} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "person_type")
public class PersonType {
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer id;

 @Column(name = "person_type_name", unique=true)
 private String personType;

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "personTypes", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
 private Set<Person> persons;
}```
````

Comment: i made a mistake. person_type_person_type_name_key is person_type_name is a column in person_type table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is with inserting the PersonType. Ensure that you put PersonType with the same ID and same name into the DB. Also change CascadeType.ALL to be CascadeType.MERGE